# What does "Cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone" mean?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

In the header:

```
...
int32_t round(float v);
...
```

and in the source

```
...
int32_t round(float v)
{
    int32_t t = (int32_t)std::floor(v);
    if((v - t) > 0.5)
        return t + 1;

    return t;
}
...
```

I've looked around here on this site but the examples seem a bit too complicated to me.

I'm learning C++ so if someone could explain to me what the error means and why it's occurring I would be grateful.

Comment: It means that there's already a `round` taking a `float` argument.

Comment: And the compiler is probably showing you the *other* `round` function.

Comment: I'm assuming you used `using namespace std;`. That would make your `int32_t round(float)` conflict with [`std::round`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

Comment: In any event, choosing a name such as `round()` for a function is begging for a name conflict somewhere.

Comment: @Bart I'm pretty certain that the issue is related to `<cmath>` or `<math.h>` and overloads appearing in the global namespace vs namespace std.

Comment: @BartvanNierop No, [that would be legal](http://ideone.com/F9jUos) to define them in differing namespaces.  It smells more like a C header is included, polluting the global namespace.

Comment: I renamed my function from ```round``` to ```roundc``` to make it different and I no longer get this error. I also found that when I call this function and "peeked the definition" with MSVC it took me to the included mat.h instead of my definition. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

*[Function overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading)* means to have multiple methods with the same name.

Now, the compiler, to resolve the correct overloaded method, looks at method name and arguments but NOT at the return value. This means that if you have

```
int round(float something) { ... }
float round(float something) { ... }
```

Then the compiler is not able to distinguish them and know which one you want to invoke at a call point. So in your case this means that there is already another `round` method which accepts a `float`.

Comment: This explanation cleared all up for me. I added a comment on my original post in regards to the resolution of this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

C++ standard doesn't support overloading based on return type alone, it's because the return type doesn't play a role in determining the function being called. The return type is only determined at runtime, and thus it's not part of the function signature which is used by the compiler to decide which function to call.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class complex
{
private:
    int real;
    int img;

public:
    void set(int r, int i)
    {
        real = r;
        img = i;
    }
    complex(int r = 0, int i = 0)
    {
        real = r;
        img = i;
    }
    int getReal(){
        return real ;
    }
    int getImg(){
        return img ;
    }
    friend complex operator+(complex x, complex y);
    friend void Display(complex y);
    
};
/*freind functions of complex*/
complex operator+(complex x, complex y)
{
    complex z;
    z.real = x.getReal() + y.getReal();
    z.img = x.getImg() + y.getImg();
    return z;
}
void Display(complex y)
{

    cout << y.getReal()<< "+i" << y.getImg() << endl;
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    complex c1, c2, c3;
    c1.set(78, 9);
    c2.set(68, 9);
    c3 = c1 + c2;
    c1.Display(c3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem too like this, I am getting a problem in Display it says cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

Comment: tho it is  a friend function but not accessible for class complex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Fix your complex class `friend int Display(complex y);` to `friend int Display(complex y);`

And next time please do not try to answer a question with another question...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31582759)

Comment: I really apologize for that but I'm always not able to post my codes on StackOverflow it always shows some kind of error [Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your questions as code] even I explain the code very properly then also the error occurs. that's why I tried the comment section for code. I'm sorry.

Comment: and your solution didn't helped me the code is as it is .